# What's the meaning of Modality in Simple English?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was recently applying for Admission to my desired college and they released a PDF called "Admissions Modality".

Dictionary shows the meaning of Modality as the quality of being "modal". The meaning of Modal is "relating to mode or form as opposed to substance".

I'm out of my wits here. Can someone please explain in simple terms what all of these words mean?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of admission to a university or other higher-education institutions, "admissions modality" or "admission modalities" (both forms are used) refers to the conditions that applicants need to fulfil before they can enter that university or institution.

For example, some universities look at school results, some will require that you take an entrance exam, and some will want to interview you (typically after looking at school results).

This usage of "modality" is not covered by any of the meanings listed at [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modality). The phrase "admission modalities" seems to be common in India but [rare in the UK](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22admission+modalities%22+site%3Auk&t=ffab&ia=web), for example.

Comment: Interesting. "Modality" is also uncommon in the U.S., as you cannot qualify for admission to a university on any mutually exclusive sets of qualifications. The term *modality* has been popularized amidst the COVID-19 pandemic as referring to the mode of instruction: remote, in-person, in-person transitioning to remote, and innumerable hybrid models.